# Query for a class with multiple pointers in Parse database

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I have a "Event" class in Parse DB which has two pointers called "Feature" and "Network". See below for reference:

[image]

I want to retrieve objects from Event class which have the selected array of features and in the selected networks. 
I tried to do the query as below:

```
func getEventsByFilter(networks: [Network]?, features: [Feature]?,completion: (events: [Event]?, error: NSError?) -> ()) {
    let query = PFQuery(className:"Event")
    query.whereKey("feature", containedIn: features!)
    query.whereKey("network", containedIn: networks!)
```

However, I get the following error and the query returns all the events in the Events class: 
[Error]: Caught "NSInvalidArgumentException" with reason "Invalid type in JSON write (MyApp.Network)":

Any suggestions on how to rewrite the query so that I can get events that are in the selected networks and having the features that are selected?

Any help appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: do you have arrays networks and features defined as PFObject ?

Comment: @MazelTov: Feature and Network are two different classes in my project. They inherit from NSObject and have initialization through PFObject.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure features and networks are an array of Strings (NSStrings for objC).

Parse keys are always of type String, of either objectID or whatever key value is stored.

**EDIT**

Forgot to add for "containedIn:" parse will be expecting an Array of Strings as the parameter.

```
PFQuery *categoryQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kClassnameCategory];
[categoryQuery whereKey:kKeyCategoryName equalTo:self.listCategory];
[categoryQuery getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject * category, NSError * _Nullable error) {
```

The above code [categoryQuery whereKey: equalTo:] is expecting a String for both of the parameter to find a match since all Parse keys are Strings.  In the case of containedIn: it would be expecting an Array of Strings.

Comment: Will give this a try and let you know if it resolves my issue. Thanks for the help!